go,sqlc, postgres: unknown driver "postgres" (forgoten import?)
el problema es el que dice el titulo, estoy empezando con go y postgres,
mi codigo
//main.go

package main

import (
"database/sql"
"log"
_ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"
)
const(
     DBDriver = "postgres"
     DBSource = "postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/mybd?sslmode=disable"
)

func main(){
conn, err := sql.Open(DBDriver, DBSource)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("couldn't stablish connection with db: ", err)
    }
err = server.Start("0.0.0.0:3000")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("cannot start server", err)
    }
}

en consola ejecuto go run main.go y me tira el error unknown driver "postgres" (forgoten import?) cual puede ser el error

Como ejecutas? Haces go get . y go run .?

El nombre del driver es incorrecto:  DBDriver = "postgres" debería ser https://github.com/jackc/pgx

Estas usando https://github.com/jackc/pgx, pero estás definiendo como Driver: "postgres", lo cual es incorrecto, cambia el nombre del Driver
     DBDriver = "pgx" //DBDriver = "postgres"

También cambia la importación del Driver, realiza los cambios:
import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"
    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/stdlib" //* Cambiar 
)

const (
    DBDriver = "pgx" //* Cambiar
    DBSource = "postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/mybd?sslmode=disable"
)


modifique el codigo como sugeriste, cambie el import dejando _ "github.com/jackc/pgx", ahora me dejo obtener el modulo, pero al hacer el cambio de driver y reemplazar postgres por pgx me sigue arrojando el mismo error

@HernanS realiza un cambio en la importación, revisa la edición de la respuesta.
